# MVC C# Application error to show messagebox.show

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

When running my MVC4 application in Visual Studio 2015 her regular runs and runs everything right in the browser , ultilizo MessageBox.Show in the middle of code, saw in some places using the same and usually not a problem.

I used in developing Framework 4.6 that is I have it installed on my machine that will be the server Enforcement, my IIS 7 and it is my UserAppPool only has the framework v4.0.30319 .

I dont need use messageBox, but this is only solution that i find, have another option for show message for the user ?

When you open the application in the browser opens normal to click the button to perform the actions and generate the messagebox it generates the error below :

```
Erro de Servidor no Aplicativo '/'.

Mostrar um formulário ou uma caixa de diálogo restrita quando o aplicativo não está no modo UserInteractive não é uma operação válida. Especifique o estilo ServiceNotification ou DefaultDesktopOnly para exibir uma notificação de um aplicativo de serviços.

Descrição: Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento durante a execução da atual solicitação da Web. Examine o rastreamento de pilha para obter mais informações sobre o erro e onde foi originado no código. 

Detalhes da Exceção: System.InvalidOperationException: Mostrar um formulário ou uma caixa de diálogo restrita quando o aplicativo não está no modo UserInteractive não é uma operação válida. Especifique o estilo ServiceNotification ou DefaultDesktopOnly para exibir uma notificação de um aplicativo de serviços.

Erro de Origem: 


Linha 1:  @{
Linha 2:      ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
Linha 3:  }
Linha 4:  <br />

Arquivo de Origem: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mm_solution\Views\Home\Index.cshtml    Linha: 2 

Rastreamento de Pilha: 


[InvalidOperationException: Mostrar um formulário ou uma caixa de diálogo restrita quando o aplicativo não está no modo UserInteractive não é uma operação válida. Especifique o estilo ServiceNotification ou DefaultDesktopOnly para exibir uma notificação de um aplicativo de serviços.]
   System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.ShowCore(IWin32Window owner, String text, String caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon, MessageBoxDefaultButton defaultButton, MessageBoxOptions options, Boolean showHelp) +2994248
   MM_Solution_2.Controllers.HomeController.SendMessage(String test) +1609
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +104
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1.<WrapVoidAction>b__0(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassa.<EndProcessRequest>b__9() +22
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Wrap>b__3() +10
   System.Web.Mvc.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap(Func`1 func) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap(Action action) +64
   System.Web.Mvc.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +71
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride) +1556

[HttpException (0x80004005): Erro ao executar a solicitação filho do manipulador 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.]
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride) +3424518
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage) +77
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm) +29
   System.Web.HttpServerUtilityWrapper.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm) +24
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.ActionHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, TextWriter textWriter) +463
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.Action(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues) +83
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.Action(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName) +9
   ASP._Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml.Execute() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mm_solution\Views\Home\Index.cshtml:2
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +197
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +105
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +17
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +64
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +78
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +256
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +107
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +291
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +173
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9711525
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Below is information in the browser:

```
Informações sobre a Versão: Microsoft .NET Framework Versão:4.0.30319; Versão do ASP.NET:4.6.81.0
```

Comment: You can't have a MessageBox in an asp.net application

Comment: Don't understand the question, can't read the error, and you're trying to use a `MessageBox` in a web application.  Nothing here makes sense, sorry.

Comment: @stuartd no, i dont need use messageBox, but this is only solution that i find, you have another option for show message for the user ?

Comment: @David no, i dont need use messageBox, but this is only solution that i find, you have another option for show message for the user ?

Comment: @JhonnyPamponet: You can show anything you like to the user in the resulting HTML.  There are *countless* ways to show a message to a user on a web page.

Comment: @David yes, I know, but in MVC4 I don't have sucess with another codes

Comment: @JhonnyPamponet: You're going to have to show what you've tried and explain how it's not working as expected.  At the moment the only suggestion I have for you is to start with some introductory tutorials on web development and ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @David, this is a example: ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", "Primeira etapa concluída com sucesso!");

Comment: @David but the VS2015 speak: ClientScrip does not exist in the current context!

Comment: @JhonnyPamponet: Then it sounds like `ClientScript` doesn't exist in MVC. (Thankfully, I might add. That stuff was awful in WebForms.) Ideally any message you want to display would be part of the view model or, at worst, part of something like `ViewBag` or `TempData`. Then in the view you'd use that value to display a message to the user. I'd recommend something in the HTML instead of an `alert()` but you can use an `alert()` if you really want to. The point is... The controller sets the value on the model, the view reads the value from the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment thread so far...

If you just want to send a "message" from the controller to the view, you can set that as a property on the model:

```
someModel.SomeProperty = "Some Message";
```

or, at worst, as part of something like `ViewData`:

```
ViewData["SomeProperty"] = "Some Message";
```

Then, in the view, you'd display it.  Ideally this would be something more elegant than an `alert()`.  You can include it in the markup:

```
@if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.SomeProperty)) {
    <div id="message">@Model.SomeProperty</div>
}
```

Then you can apply any styling or effects you want to that `div`.  But if you *really want* to use an `alert()`, that would work the same way:

```
@if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.SomeProperty)) {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert('@Model.SomeProperty');
    </script>
}
```

(You may need to use `<text></text>` tags judiciously when putting JavaScript code in Razor blocks.  Sometimes the syntax confuses the rendering engine.)

Comment: <form action="" method="post" id="frm_txtarea" >
        <center><textarea id="test" name="test"  style="max-width:90%; height:200px; width:90%; font-size: 12px;"></textarea></center>
        <br />
        
       <center><button id="btn_chris" onclick="@Html.Action("SendMessage")" >enviar</button></center>
        <br />
        
    </form>
    <br />

    <text>@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.SomeProperty))
    {
        <script type="text/javascript">
        alert('@Model.SomeProperty');
        </script>
    }
    </text>

Comment: but show error messageAn exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Não é possível fazer associação em tempo de execução em uma referência nula

Comment: @JhonnyPamponet: Well, does your model have a property called `SomeProperty`?  (Or whatever you decide to call it.)  Also, I can't read that error message, so I can only guess what it says.  It also looks like you're using `<text>` tags incorrectly, though I can't be certain just by looking at it.